# How does this C code produce stack overflow on execution? What are the execution steps?

Tags: c, function, stack, output

I am unable to understand how this C code produces stack overflow on execution? What are the execution steps? Kindly help.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main()                     //Main function
    {
        reverse(1);
    }

    void reverse(int i)               //Reverse function
    {
        if (i > 5)
            exit(0);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        return reverse(i++);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `i++` and `++i`?

Comment: Have you run it and observed what is printed?

Comment: BTW, your `reverse(i++)` recursive call is actually a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Some compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) used as `gcc -O2`) are able to do the tail call optimization, so won't give any stack overflow when running the compiled program.

Comment: thanks...this is not a code I wrote for anything...This is a question I saw in C MCQ's ...to tell the output of this code

Comment: Well, do you not think it might be more instructive for you to run the code line-by-line under a debugger before asking for any extended explanation here?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    reverse(1);
}

void reverse(int i)
{
    if (i > 5)
        exit(0);

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return reverse(i++);
}
```

on this line `return reverse(i++);` you tell to your code to add 1 to i AFTER the return which is a non-sense

you must do `return reverse(++i);`
it will add 1 to i just BEFORE the return

it's why your programm crashes. Then one more thing don't use return on a void function

choose between

```
int reverse(int i)
```

or

```
reverse(++i); // last line
```

FINAL CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit function

int reverse(int i)
{
    if (i > 5)
        exit(0);

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return reverse(++i);
}

int main()
{
    reverse(1);
}
```

EDIT for the second question in the comments of this post

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit function                                                                                                                                                                        

void reverse(int i) {
  if (i > 5)
    return ;

  printf("%d ", i);
  return reverse((i++, i));
}

int main()
{
  reverse(1);
}
```

i have to tell you i never saw this synthax before but as i tell you when you do `action(i++);` i's new value is set AFTER action is performed (it's called a post incrementation, where as `++i` called a pre incrementation)
here adding `(i++, i)` allow you to get the i value set at i + 1 with a post incrementation. This synthax is totally unuseful you should use `++i`
 instead. `(i++, i)` it's just a way to say do a post incrementation, but do it now (which is a non-sense)

Comment: thanks...this is not a code I wrote for anything...This is a question I saw in C MCQ's ...to tell the output of this code

Comment: or then i hope my post helped you to understand what was the problem and how it was possible to fix it

Comment: yes, very clearly explained. Thanks a lot. Can you also explain another similar code ?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

        void reverse(int i);

        int main()

        {

            reverse(1);

        }

        void reverse(int i)

        {

            if (i > 5)

                return ;

            printf("%d ", i);

            return reverse((i++, i));

        }

Comment: @RajeshSh i will edit my post and give you an explanation

Comment: I do not understand this statement:    return reverse((i++, i));    reverse only takes one argument. So how come it takes two here? Why doesn't this give error?

Comment: @RajeshSh as you can see (i++, i) is wrapped between paranthesis, it's only one value. (i++, i) is like i + 1, but the incrementation is not done after the statement, but at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Your function is called recursively with the argument of *1* over and over until there is no more space on the stack. 
I think you want to use `++i` instead of `i++`.

Comment: thanks...this is not a code I wrote for anything...This is a question I saw in C MCQ's ...to tell the output of this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
return reverse(i++);
```

This line calls `reverse` with the current value of `i`, **then** increments it. This means that you are calling `reverse(1)` infinitely many times (or at least trying to; eventually, as you have noticed, the stack is filled up and you encounter a stack overflow).

Also, returning a `void` function doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about **expressions** and **side effects**. An expression has a value when evaluated, like `1 + 2` has the value `3`. A side effect changes some state.

The `++` and `--` operators in C give you both: they evaluate to some value, and as a side effect, they change the variable. Both `++i` and `i++` add `1` to `i` (the side effect), but `++i` evaluates to the value of i **after** incrementing it, while `i++` evaluates to the value **before** incrementing it.

As you are writing a recursive function, you don't need side effects at all! It's often the whole point of recursion to avoid side effects (they are forbidden in *functional programming*, so recursion is an often-used technique there). So, just write your implementation free of side-effects:

```
    return reverse(i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is that your recursive function `void reverse(int i)` is called on `1` again and again. 
This is because of the line - `return reverse(i++);`
`i++` is a postfix expression.
 
The result of the postfix increment or decrement operation is the value of the operand. After the result is obtained, the value of the operand is incremented (or decremented).
To avoid the stackoverflow problem you can replace  - `return reverse(i++);` by `return reverse(++i);` or by `reverse(i+1);`

Answer (score 0):

The other part are explained in the others answers but since it's a `void` function you just ignore the keyword `return` also puting prototype before the `main` is good to use.
Since this function is a recursive function, calling it once from the `main` with the argument `1` start the function and it continue to call it self recursively until the condition in `if` statement is true.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 void reverse(int);
    int main() {
        reverse(1);
    }

 void reverse(int i){
        if (i > 5)
            exit(0);
        printf("%d\n", i);
       reverse(++i);
    }
```